# Does dweller health regenerate faster when the game is open?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Early in the game I don't have access to a lot of stimpacks. So when a wasteland explorer returns to the shelter, I like to wait for their health to regenerate naturally before sending them back out.

Will the dweller's health regenerate faster if I leave the game open, or should I just close the game and check back once their health bar is full?